# Why does C++ require low-level const qualification on both objects when copying an object to another?

Tags: c++, oop, object, constants

I was reading *C++-Primer* (by Josée Lajoie and Stanley B. Lippman) when I came across this section about top-level and low-level `const`s. On one paragraph, it says that when copying an object, top level `const`s are ignored.

Eg.

```
const int i = 24;
int i2 = i;
```

Where the top-level `const` qualification in *i* is ignored when copied into *i2*.

However, it also states

> On the other hand, low-level `const` is never ignored. When we copy an object, both objects must have the same low-level `const` qualification or there must be a conversion between the types of the two objects. In general, we can convert a non`const` to `const` but not the other way around.

Now, usually when C++ has a rule like this there's a reason behind them. I find that understanding them is fundamental to understanding the rule and therefore making it easier to memorize (this is like understanding a mathematic concept instead of memorizing formulas). However, there's no logical rule I find that fits into the puzzle here.

As a summary, my question is:

1. Why is that when copying an object the top-level `const` qualification is ignored? (There's a section explaining why in the book too, but I can't seem to get it)

> Copying and object doesn't change the copied object. As a result, it is immaterial whether the object copied from or copied into is `const`

2. What's the reason behind how low-level `const` is never ignored when copying an object? (low-level `const` qualification is needed on both objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Top level case: You make a copy of the const object, so it doesn't matter if your copy is const or not, because (assuming const-correct types) you can't modify the original via the copy.

Low level case: You make a copy of a *handle* to another object. The original handle does not allow modification of the object it refers to. Allowing to ignore the low level const would mean you can obtain a handle that allows you to modify the referred object, breaking const correctness.

It would allow this kind of craziness:

```
// should not modify n, right?
void foo(const int& n)
{
    int& mutable_n = n;
    mutable_n = 42;
}

...

int n = 0;
foo(n); // should not modify n, right?
std::cout << n << '\n'; // prints 42, wat??
```

Comment: I think you meant `mutable_n=42;` instead of `n=42;`

Comment: thanks very much. however, I've also happen to see that writing code like `int& n` is a bad practice (is it?). other than that, great answer! here - get some sweet internet points.

Comment: @Quimby I think doing that wouldn't let n become 42 even in the end.

Comment: @CharUTF what do you mean `int& n` is bad practice? Declaring references is bad practice??

Comment: @bolov okay I take that back. After doing some further reading I realize this might not be the case. Instead, I think it meant that this code:

    `int& i, i2;`

is bad practice. (since it gives the notion that both `i` and `i2` are int references when they're not - only `i` is)